# optimizing the DELETE statement with a count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Which of the following two statements would you consider to be the most effective for deleting large number of rows?

Statement #1:

```
DELETE TOP (@count) FROM ProductInfo WHERE productId = @productid
```

Statement #2: Derived table

```
DELETE t1 FROM (SELECT TOP (@count) * from ProductInfo 
                WHERE productId = @productId v) t1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both and neither. You need to delete in batches when dealing with a large number, because of single transaction log growth issues. Assuming you want to delete all records for a given @productId:

```
declare @batchSize int = 10000;
do while(1=1)
begin
   delete top(@batchSize) from ProductInfo where productId = @productId;
   if (0 = @@rowcount)
      break;
end
```

The two forms of DELETE you posted are basically identical, the important thing is the table is organized by a clustered key based on `productId` key. If this is not true and you have a NC index on `productId` then the @batchSize has to be calibrated as to avoid the [index tipping point](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Tipping-Point-Query-Answers.aspx).

Comment: 1. What happens if the delete statement fails? Does it continue in the while loop?

2. What happens if the delete fails, does it set the rowcount = 0 and falsly exit the loop?

Comment: Adding error handling to every single example post would bloat the sample and dilute the value of the example. But if you explicitly ask for error handling, then I would recommend wrapping this in a BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH block. You then deal with the error appropriately, based on what was the error.

Comment: A @batchSize that large will lead to Lock Escalation unless it has specifically been disabled through various methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since both queries perform the exact same task, I'd use the first one, because it's simpler to read and understand.

(Also, since both queries do the same work, I suspect that they'd generate the same execution plan--can you check this?)